# Use Same Scale for Axis and Bubble Sizes in Bubble Size Chart Excel

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I've been dwelling on the Internet for a long time before understanding how Bubble Charts work in Excel. Now it seems logical to me that the Bubbles have their own scale to represent data in a way that is neat and clean for the average user.

However, I'm facing a problem where I need to have the option to get "real-sized" Bubbles on a Bubble Chart. And I'm a bit desperate on how to achieve this in a simple way.

I need to display costs estimates, alongside with an end date, and a risk that's also an amount in dollars. I want to be able to display them as bubbles, so that each month, we can easily see the variation in cost, delay, and risk estimates.

To me, the simplest way to display all of it is the Bubble Chart. But the Bubbles are not scaled the same as the Y-Axis.

My data looks as follows :

[Raw Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPN1j.png)

[Bubble Graph Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMh6R.png)

My questions are :

- **How can I scale the Bubble Size to the same value as the Y-Axis?**
- **Is there a better way for me to do this rather than the solution I'm using?**

Comment: To answer your second question, could you explain you want to use bubbles?  There are plenty of other options, but if there's something specific driving you to bubbles that precludes other options that's important to know.

Comment: I wanted to find a solution that let people easily see the 3 variables (cost, delays, risks) and their evolution each time a measure of the situation is done. It's just a choice I made to display my 3 values and their evolution.